# Warning MSB3243, conflict between signed and unsigned assemblies

Tags: .net, msbuild

I've got a project with a NuGet package reference to `snt.ScintillaNet.FindReplaceDialog`.
This package in turn has a reference to the unsigned package `ScintillaNET`.

My application has to be signed so I referenced the signed version of the `ScintillaNET` package.
This works well and the application is working fine. 
However when building I get the following warning:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2106,5): warning MSB3243: No way to resolve conflict between "ScintillaNET, Version=3.6.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d42c48f11a620156" and "ScintillaNET, Version=3.6.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null". Choosing "ScintillaNET, Version=3.6.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d42c48f11a620156" arbitrarily.

This makes sense, the build system sees 2 references, one signed and one unsigned.
It then picks up the one I want (signed) and everything works fine.

I want to remove that warning from the build.
I tried to put `MSB3243` as a warning exception in the project, but as it's a MSBuild warning and not a compiler warning it cannot be ignored.

I came up with a very ugly hack that I'm going to put down as an answer to help anyone else that comes across the same issue (and myself when I forget my solution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get around the issue I ask the build system to ignore the unsigned version.
To do that I explicitly added the unsigned version of the NuGet package to the project together with the signed version.
Then I manually changed the reference in the .csproj file to the following:

`<!-- Hack to prevent the unsigned library to load and raise an assembly conflict -->
<PackageReference Include="jacobslusser.ScintillaNET">
  <Version>3.6.3</Version>
  <ExcludeAssets>all</ExcludeAssets>
</PackageReference>`

This prevents all artifacts from being copied during the NuGet package resolution.

It's ugly but works so I'd like to get a cleaner way of achieving the same effect.